# Specifying a SLOT in another class

Tags: c++, qt, events, signals

I would like to specify a slot from within another class to execute on button click, how does one do this?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,SLOT(Slotindiffrentclass);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Searching, and [reading](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

```
QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 differentClass,SLOT(Slotindiffrentclass);
```

Comment: You might want to say that `differentClass` is a pointer to an *instance* of the class `Slotindifferentclass`.

Comment: `differentClass` is a pointer to an instance of the class _owning the slot_ `Slotindifferentclass`

Comment: Thanks, I though it had something to do with the 3rd row of connect. I tried to create a new instance of the class FileProcessor in the main window class and its telling me its and undeclared identifer. Something like FileProcessor p; QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 p,SLOT(Slotindiffrentclass);

Comment: Should be: `QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()), &p,SLOT(Slotindiffrentclass);`. The third parameter of the connect is a pointer to the class.

Comment: Anyway my suggestion is to read the doc and see the examples too.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd argument in `connect` is a pointer to a class where a slot is located. So just replace `this` with a pointer to a needed class.